# How to align Footer text Properly

Tags: css

[image: Screenshot]

This is my website footer . as you an see it's not well aligned . i just need to align the text . list header and sub listings should come in same alignment . how can i do that ? i've used UL and LI

Comment: Can you please post your html css code for this. If possible in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I fixed for you - http://i.imgur.com/NsHKorh.jpg :)

Comment: Yeah here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/U9CEf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `display:inline` on the `UL` elements, all you have to add is `vertical-align:top`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the following CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#footer {
    background-color: rgb(70,221, 93);
    height:250px;
    padding:40px 0;
    width:100%;
}

#footer > div {

    text-align:center;
    width:24%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;     /* See this line its important for all the 'headers' to align properly */
}
#footer > div > span {
    margin:0 0 30px 0;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;

}

a {
    display:block;
    color:White;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/StARu/

Hope this helps!!!